# HttpWebRequest AddRange Method Query

Tags: c#, http

In HttpWebRequest AddRange method, we can specify the range of byte to download. What I want to know is how to specify my range from a certain offset upto the end of file.

Like if we don't know the length of the file, we can specify like this in the Request Header string

"Range: bytes = 0 - " This means, starting from the first byte upto the end of file.

But using the method AddRange, how to specify this with one offset value to the EOF??

I know I can get the content length and specify like this, AddRange(0, ContentLength). But I am asking if there is any way to get the contents upto EOF from a certain 'offset' value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a positive value to the AddRange method to get bytes from the offset to the end of entity;

```
 request.AddRange(10)
```

Tells the server to return all bytes except the first 10.

You can use a negative value, which is the ending point;

```
 request.AddRange(-10)
```

Tells server to return bytes 0 to 10.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fy67z6d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Method with a starting value different then 0.

Something like this:

```
myHttpWebRequest.AddRange(50,ContentLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification for ranges](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35),

> If the last-byte-pos value is absent, or if the value is greater than
>   or equal to the current length of the entity-body, last-byte-pos is
>   taken to be equal to one less than the current length of the entity-
>   body in bytes.

In other words, your `Range: bytes = 0 -` is supposed to work. In fact, the `HttpWebRequest` has a method, [AddRange(Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ds43y3w.aspx), that does exactly what you're asking for.